# Pseudocode for defining binary file

Tags: structure, pseudocode

For describing how an algorithm works you can use pseudocode. What would you use to define a structure of binary file? For instance, I have a file that has the following structure:

```
(n) - int32 containing number of files
then, repeated n times:
    (len) - int32 containing length of file name
    (name) - len bytes containing file name
    (size) - file size
    (offset) - offset from file start from which starts file contents
```

Which way is the best to describe file structure like this?

Comment: [ABNF](https://tools.ietf.org/html/std68)?

Comment: @Kay not sure how it would help